# T-SQL: Displaying values or not in record list

Tags: t-sql

I have a table of customers, orders, and items.  I'd like to write a report with one customer per row (for this example I'm assuming one order per customer) and whether certain items were ordered.

***customers***:

```
id  
firstName
```

***orders***:

```
id
customers_id
```

***items***:

```
id
orders_id
```

I'm having problems displaying a row if a particular item has not been ordered (e.g. apples)

What I'd like is a report with 3 columns:

- First Name
- Apples
- Bananas

Here is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT c.firstName, i_apple, i_banana
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.customers_id
LEFT JOIN items i_apple ON o.id = i_apple.orders_id
LEFT JOIN items i_banana ON o.id = i_banana.orders_id
WHERE i_apple = 'apple' AND i_banana = 'banana'
```

Comment: You will get more attention if you add `sql` and `sql-server-version` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine, but you need to filter outer joins in ON clause of the join, otherwise you turn outer into an inner join. I've added `Name` column to Items but it should probably be `ProductID`, a foreign key to Product table with ProductName.

```
SELECT c.firstName, i_apple.Name Apple, i_banana.Name Banana
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN orders o 
  ON c.id = o.customers_id
LEFT JOIN items i_apple 
  ON o.id = i_apple.orders_id
 AND i_apple.Name = 'apple'
LEFT JOIN items i_banana 
  ON o.id = i_banana.orders_id
 AND i_banana.Name = 'banana'
```